# What is the difference between Expo CLI and Expo SDK

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on expo project by following online tutorials. I used **npm install -g expo-cli** to install the CLI. I also used **expo init AwesomeProject** to initialize a new expo project. Later i came to know that there is something called **expo SDK** and the latest version as of today is 42. So, i decided to check mine using **expo --version**. I got 4.3.2 as result and i can upgrade it to 4.9.1 by running **npm install -g expo-cli**. I realized that it is nothing do to with SDK version. Now i am confused with expo CLI and SDK because the tutorial doesn't even tell anything about SDK. Is it important to know about expo SDK ? and what's the difference between expo CLI and expo SDK and how to check its version? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Expo CLI is the set of commands that you use to interact with the Expo ecosystem to build, run and deploy your app. For ex: `expo init`, `expo install`, `expo start`, `expo eject` etc., commands are all part of the CLI.

Expo SDK is the set of packages that you 'import' for building your app. For eg: `expo-location`, `expo-calendar` are all packages that are part of SDK: Check out: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v43.0.0/sdk/. The set of packages and their functionality vary for each SDK version.

When you run a command like

> expo install expo-location

, you are using the expo's `install` command to install **expo-location** package for the SDK you are currently on.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, each version of Expo CLI is dependent on an SDK version and many other dependencies, and you should not update any dependency separately. You should wait for a new version of Expo CLI and when updating, probably, it will also update the version of the SDK. Expo CLI is just a command line that put together all expo dependencies and facilitates his installation in new projects. Expo SDK is the actual software that you use when you `start expo` and that gives your app access to multiple APIs.